# Flexbox vertical centering only if screen height is enough

Tags: css, flexbox

I have verticaly centered element with flexbox method, but i need it to be aligned from top with scroll option, if screen height is not enough to show whole element in center mode.

Is something like that possible with flexbox?

Many thanks!

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.flex>div {
  background: green;
  padding: 5vw;
  width: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem
      ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolor Lorem<br><br><br> ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolorLorem
      ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum
      dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolor</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, i don't know the context , but with CSS , the height is automatically expended to allow scroll when the content is larger than screen. With this trick , you can remove the absolute position (hard to fix for responsive) and use the native flexbox height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `bottom: 0` to fill the whole screen height, you can use `min-height: 100vh;` to *at least*  fill the whole screen height, but leave open the option to expand if the contents are higher.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.flex>div {
  background: green;
  padding: 5vw;
  width: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem
      ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolor Lorem<br><br><br> ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolorLorem
      ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum
      dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolor</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the absolute position in the flex class. This should be enough.

```css
.flex{display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; background: red;}
.flex>div{background: green; padding: 5vw; width: 50vw;}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolor Lorem<br><br><br> ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolor</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But this is deforming .flex div, which is not on full height. Answer before this from Johannes is ideal. But still thanks for try!